# C++ - Change the type of an object

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overriding

**In brief:**

Is it possible to change the type of an object once established?

**What I've tried:**

For instance given the design:
(edit: To clarify, this is a simplified example of a strategy design pattern, it isn't important what `ChangeData` does, only that we can change what it does by changing `_interface`)

```
struct MyClass
{
    int _data;
    MyInterface* _interface;

    void DoChangeData() { Interface->ChangeData(*this); }
};

MyClass x;
x._interface = new DerivedClass1();
x.DoChangeData(); // do something
x._interface = new DerivedClass2();
x.DoChangeData(); // do something else
```

switching `_interface` allows us to change the operations upon the class, however this necessitates creating wrapper methods (`DoChangeData`) and always passing the `this` pointer as an argument, which is ugly.

A better solution I would prefer is:

```
struct MyClass abstract
{
    int _data;

    virtual void ChangeData() = 0;
};
```

But here once the concrete class is established, unlike `_interface`, it cannot be changed. It seems like this should be possible providing the different derived classes don't add any new fields. Is there any way to implement the `ChangeClass` function below?

```
DerivedClass1 x;
x.DoChangeData(); // do something
x.ChangeClass(DerivedClass2); // ???
x.DoChangeData(); // do something else
```

Note I am talking about virtual classes, and `reinterpret_cast` only works with non-virtual objects. Copy constructors require the overhead of moving existing memory, which I would also rather avoid.

Comment: This is known as the [envelope–letter design pattern](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/cpp/envelope/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the kind of question that can be better answered if you explain the actual problem rather than how to implement your solution.

It is not clear to me what `DoChangeData` should do and why it requires a reference to `MyClass`. 
The problem statement is not clear enough to get an answer, and the title (as stated) would get a **no** as an answer (in C++ you can not change types, is a strongly typed language), but I understand is not what you are asking.

Please clarify the question to be able to get a satisfying answer.

BTW, you may want to pay a look at the [Visitor design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and/or the [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: Isn't the stragegy pattern what is shown in the example? I'll add some clarification, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry didn't review the code carefully enough. It is nice to leave the name as reference though ;-)

Comment: I your edit you say "...it isn't important what ChangeData does, only that we can change what it does by changing _interface". Because `changeData` needs to access the container object (at least in the example), I **do** think it is important what is the intention (that's why I originally asked for a clarification, I think you may face the design in another way). If what you need is a way to change how `MyClass` is processed, you may want to invert the "dependency" and use something like a Visitor design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare function pointers in `MyClass` and change them to change the type.  Or create your own vtable with a (const pointer) to an array of function pointers, and just change this pointer to change the type.

Comment: All these are true but, IMHO, are not better than the alternative already implemented. These are "hacks" to be used when you don't have polymorphism (e.g. if using C), not in C++. That's why I think further details are required to really help the OP.